# How to download an RPM package from an open source repo to a Windows 10 machine using the JFrog CLI?

Tags: jfrog-cli

I have been trying to download a software package (coTURN 4.5.2) from EPEL oracle repository onto my Windows 10 laptop using the command

`jf rt dl https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/developer/EPEL/x86_64/getPackage/coturn-4.5.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm`

and I get the following response

```
Log path: C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\.jfrog\logs\jfrog-cli.2022-05-12.11-44-52.17960.log
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

and when I look at the logs, they say

`[Info] Searching items to download...`

I have verified that I have configured my CLI with the right Artifactory information and credentials. Can someone please help me on how to download the package on to my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to download the uncached artifacts from remote repositories using JFrog CLI. Please refer to below comment from [CLI wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) page.

> Remote download
>
> By default, the command only downloads files which are cached on the
> current Artifactory instance. It does not download files located on
> remote Artifactory instances, through remote or virtual repositories.
> To allow the command to download files from remote Artifactory
> instances, which are proxied by the use of remote repositories, set
> the JFROG_CLI_TRANSITIVE_DOWNLOAD_EXPERIMENTAL environment variable to
> true. This functionality requires version 7.17 or above of
> Artifactory.
>
> The remote download functionality is supported only on remote
> repositories which proxy repositories on remote Artifactory instances.
> Downloading through a remote repository which proxies non Artifactory
> repositories is not supported.

And also, please note the syntax should looks like "*jf rt dl <-repository-name->/<-path-to-artifact->*".